# Joining Products Table with Custom Module Table (Adding Product Thumbnails to Custom Grid)

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, custom, product-images, join-table

I created a custom module with a grid and needed to display product thumbnail images there.
Tried codes from the answer below and the thumbnails were added, BUT ALL MY OTHER COLUMNS IN THE GRID ARE BLANK NOW. 
How can I join the tables correctly?

..\app\code\local\Cpstest\ProductComment\Block\Adminhtml\Cps\Grid.php

```
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
    $this->addColumn('thumbnail',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('cpstest_productcomment')->__('Thumbnail'),
        'renderer'  => 'cpstest_productcomment/adminhtml_grid_renderer_image',
            'index'     => 'thumbnail',
            'sortable'  => true,
            'filter'    => false,
            'width'     => 90,
    ));
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
    // Get and set our collection for the grid
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
    //$collection = your collection
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $collection->joinAttribute('thumbnail', 'catalog_product/thumbnail', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());/**/
    $collection->joinField('id',
    'cpstest_productcomment/cps', //check namespace/modelname
    'id',
    'id=entity_id', 
    null,
    'left');        
    $this->setCollection($collection);      
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

And the renderer file in ...\app\code\local\Cpstest\ProductComment\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\Image.php

```
    <?php
    class Cpstest_ProductComment_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
    {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
    try
    {
    $size    = 70;
    if (!$row->getThumbnail())
    {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getEntityId());
        if ($product)
        {
            if ($product->getThumbnail())
            {
                $row->setThumbnail($product->getThumbnail());
            }
        }
    }
    $url     = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($row, 'thumbnail')->resize($size)->__toString();
    if ($url)
    {
        $html  = '';
        $html .= '<img src="' . $url . '" alt="" width="' . $size . '" height="' . $size . '" />';
        return $html;
    }
    } catch (Exception $e) { /* no file uploaded */ }
    return '';
    }
    }
```

[image: All my other fields for the grid are blank now]

Here is the table structure for my custom grid:

[image: Here is the table structure for my custom grid]

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

To this to work, your collection must be `catalog` type.

First add this in your `_prepareCollection()`

```
//$collection = your collection
$store = $this->_getStore();
$collection->joinAttribute('thumbnail', 'catalog_product/thumbnail', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
```

And now in your `_prepareColumns()`

```
    $this->addColumn('thumbnail',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('your_module')->__('Thumbnail'),
            'renderer'  => 'your_module/adminhtml_your_path_to_renderer_thumb',
                'index'     => 'thumbnail',
                'sortable'  => true,
                'filter'    => false,
                'width'     => 90,
        ));
```

Now, your renderer:

```
class NameSpace_YourModule_Block_Adminhtml_Path_To_Your_Renderer_Thumb extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
  public function render(Varien_Object $row)
  {
    try
    {
        $size    = 70;

        if (!$row->getThumbnail())
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getEntityId());
            if ($product)
            {
                if ($product->getThumbnail())
                {
                    $row->setThumbnail($product->getThumbnail());
                }
            }
        }

        $url     = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($row, 'thumbnail')->resize($size)->__toString();

        if ($url)
        {
            $html  = '';
            $html .= '<img src="' . $url . '" alt="" width="' . $size . '" height="' . $size . '" />';
            return $html;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) { /* no file uploaded */ }
    return '';
}
```

This should work.

**UPDATE 1**

Add this function in Grid.php

```
protected function _getStore()
{
    $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
    return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

In order to above code work, your collection must be type of `catalog/product`. In your `_prepareCollection()` add this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

**Now, if you want to join this table with your custom table, then you can add this after above code:**

```
$collection->joinField('your_field',
        'cpstest_productcomment/cps', //check namespace/modelname
        'your_field',
        'entity_id=entity_id', 
         //catalog table has entity_id field, so your custom table which you joining must have a field containing Product Id. Otherwise it wont join.
         //if your field name is product_id then make above like: product_id = entity_id
        null,
        'left');
```

Comment: I think you should add a `$html = '<a>';`, but otherwise this looks like it should work.

Comment: @mizuti, thank, I supposed to delete that.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri  thanks for your help, but I got an error. Maybe I did something wrong? I added your codes to my question.

Comment: Could you add your `config.xml` file?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I made some corrections to the Grid.php and now I'm getting this error  a:5:{i:0;s:85:"Invalid method Cpstest_ProductComment_Block_Adminhtml_Cps_Grid::_getStore(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:4655:"#0 C:\wamp64\www\formodulecheck.dev\app\code\local\Cpstest\ProductComment\Block\Adminhtml\Cps\Grid.php(33): Varien_Object->__call('_getStore', Array)......

Comment: @Adarsh when I remove the collection codes, errors disappear, but  instead of thumbnails I see a blank column.

Comment: I added the config.php file, please take a look.

Comment: Check my update for `_getStore()` function. Also make sure you have added your `Data.php` file.

Comment: Hi @Adarsh, thanks for your help. I did like you said. Now I'm getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cpstest_ProductComment_Model_Mysql4_Cps_Collection::joinAttribute() in C:\wamp64\www\formodulecheck.dev\app\code\local\Cpstest\ProductComment\Block\Adminhtml\Cps\Grid.php on line 34

Comment: What is your `$this->_getCollectionClass()` function?  To get my code working your `$collection` should have `catalog/product` collection type. See my update how to do that.

Comment: Hi @Adarsh, it is the model that I'm using for the grid.     protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'cpstest_productcomment/cps_collection';
    }

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanations @Adarsh. I did like you said, hopefully made no mistakes, but got this error "Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "2" already exist...". I have updated my codes.

Comment: That means your table has got same product_id in multiple rows.

Comment: That's quite normal for that table, because I save there comments that users post on products and each product can have multiple comments, so each product id can be stored in that table multiple times. I tried to add the Unique Primary Key "ID" instead of the product id and it worked!! Thumbnails show up, but the other fields for the grid are blank now :( I will add the print screen, can you please take a look @Adarsh? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have declared a helper class in your module's `config.xml` file, but you have not created `Data.php` in your module's helper folder, OR vice versa.

Comment: I actually have both the helper file and necessary codes for it in the config.xml. But I tried to change the line in Grid.php Addcolumn part to this    'header'=> Mage::helper('cpstest_productcomment')->__('Thumbnail'), putting both company name and helper name and got a different error : Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on boolean in ...\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php on line 291

Comment: Put your Adminhtml folder into Block folder. And then check it.

Comment: Put your **Adminhtml** folder into **Block** folder. And then check it

Comment: I tried and also changed the renderer path in the "addcolumn..." to 'renderer'  => 'productcomment/block_adminhtml_grid_renderer_image',  but still getting the error : Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on boolean in ...\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php on line 291

Comment: don't change the path in renderer. Keep your renderer path like this ...............  `productcomment/adminhtml_grid_renderer_image` . 

And Keep your folder path like this ...........................

    `Cpstest_ProductComment_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Renderer_Image`

Comment: Hi @Dinesh, I did like you said and was getting this error Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\formodulecheck.dev\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php on line 291 and I found out that it's a sign that the renderer is  not found. So I added the company name as well like this and now there's no error nut no thumbnails as well, ust empty cells.